# the Table is Irregular when i change it's position absolute

Tags: css

in my page i have a Table like this:

```
 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <img  src="images/End_051.png" />

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="images/End_051.png" />

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td >
                             <img src="images/End_051.png" />


                        </td>
                         <td>
                             <img src="images/End_051.png" />

                         </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>
```

when i change `td` position:absolute with css the image collapsed on each other:
http://upload7.ir/images/51794162496232235063.jpg

any idea for fixing that?

Comment: Take out `position: absolute`? That's what it does.

Comment: i want it's position be absolute.

Comment: Then set the `top` and `left` attribute for each one.

Comment: it's different in each browser for example when i set top and left to 200px in firefox is good but in IE isn't good.

Comment: Why do you need them to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: please give us the cotext of why you need them positioned absolutely?

Comment: For cases such as this one, I prefer to attach the css to the img element instead..But yeah, what would you like to achieve?

Comment: i give it animation with jquery for example the image is larger when mouse over if position not absolute the whole of menu is bigger not only image.

Comment: @ AJ Naidas i do that but problem exist.

Comment: have you tried using css transitions for your cause? if you want to make it larger onmouseover you can just use css-transform's scale and :hover

Comment: `position: absolute` and the table display attributes don't play we'll together (and if you think about it, it's kinda nonsensical). If you really need the contents of a `td` positioned absolutely, wrap them in a `div` and position the `div`.

Comment: something like img:hover { transform: scale(1) }

Comment: @steveax i am testing that.

Comment: @AJ Naidas it's not only effect.

Comment: @steveax problem exist.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow of the document.

When an element is absolutely positioned, other elements behave like the absolute positioned element does not exist. This is why all of the images (which are within the `td` elements) are overlapping and stacking on top of each other.

**Here are two possible solutions:**

1. If you want to keep the elements absolutely positioned, you can  position each of the elements manually using `top: xpx` and `left: xpx`. Replacing x with the desired amount of pixels that you want to offset your image from.
2. Alternatively, you can use a [CSS3 2d transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) on
   `img:hover` to scale the images when a user hovers over them.

Here's the code for the second solution:

```
img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
img:hover{
    transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

And here's a [**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/QDquF/) for the second solution.